# how do i add a JScrollPane to this JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

(I'm new to java btw)
i have this unfinished program that and I would like to add a `jscrollpane` to the `jtextarea`. However I can't get it to work. I've tried doing

```
add(new JScollPane(area));
```

which didn't work. I tried:

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(area));
```

and that didnt't work either. I also tried:

```
area.add(pane);
```

and:

```
area.add(new JScrollPane());
```

but nothing works. HELP!!! take a look

```
public class Constructor extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 123456789L;

    JScrollPane scroll;
    public JPanel panel;
    static JTextField field;
    static JTextArea area;
    String displayCommand, commandIs;

public Constructor() {

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(getLayout());
    panel.setSize(600, 450);

    scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
    scroll.setBounds(0, 0, 10, 395);


    field = new JTextField();
    field.setSize(595, 25);
    field.setLocation(0, 400);
    field.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                showCommand(event.getActionCommand());
                field.setText("");
                }
            }
        );
    area = new JTextArea();
    area.setSize(595,395);
    area.setLocation(0,0);
    area.setEditable(false);
    area.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.BOLD, 13));
    area.setText("Welcome to JConsole! This Application is for executing commands."
            + "\nType help for more info");

    panel.add(new JScrollPane(area));
    panel.add(area);
    panel.add(field);
    add(panel);

}
```

This is just my constructor bu nothing else in the code involves the `jscrollpane`.

Comment: 2 scroll panes? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added `area` two times. First one with JScrollPane and second one without JScrollPane. You should remove second part.

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(area));
//panel.add(area); Remove this part.
```

Also make sure proper layout for `area`. By default `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, but for `JTextArea` it should be on `BorderLayout` with CENTER alignment.

Comment: i got rid of jscrollpane scroll; and stuff the changed panel.add(area); to panel.add(new jscrollpane(area)); but now my jtextarea has disappeared

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this

```
scroll.setViewportView(area);
```